# Releasing my Application to Users

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am experiencing complications when running my application on other PCs.

What can I do in Visual Studio 2012 that can ensure that any PC will run my application without complications?

These are the complications as I know them:

  1) On Windows 7, the application will not run

  2) On Windows XP, a window pop's up and shows an error stating: "Not a valid Win32 Application.".

My application is a Windows Form built in Visual Studio 2012 using Windows 7. This is my first time building an application for other users.

I found a similar related issue here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx

However, that did not resolve the error. I've made sure that the Configuration Manager target platform is Any CPU.

Comment: Hmm. Really hard to say with the information you've given us, but it's hard to know what else to ask for. Can you describe the build process you're using? Can you build *any* application, even a toy one, that your users can successfully run? Do *all* of your users have these problems, or only some?

Comment: Anyone can find it here: spellstorm-realms.tk and by clicking the download link - this is the toy application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runs okay for me on both a WinXP and Win7 machine with .NET 4.5 installed.

Can you try building against a lower framework version (under the forms project properties, change target framework to 3.5 or 4.0) and retry on the computers that failed? If it then runs correctly, you can either continue building against a lower version or optimally, make sure your installer checks the correct framework version is installed.